# Sugar stops toothache

Tags: pain, sugar, tooth-decay

My brother currently has two serious toothaches.  (Yes, he's scheduled for the dentist.)  He noticed, though, that eating bread makes the pain stop.  Later, he noticed that sugar works much better.  We were just now driving along, and he started having serious tooth pain.  He pulled into a gas station, bought some gummy bears, and now he's fine.  I've had similar, lesser, experiences - in my case, I'd eat sugar, and my teeth would hurt for a second, but as I keep eating it would go away.  Everything I google, though, says "Sugar makes my teeth hurt" etc.; I can't find anything on WHY it would make it STOP hurting.  Anybody know?

(And I'm not asking for advice.  He's already got an appointment scheduled.)